# Displaying image tag in php email

Tags: php, html, email

I don't know why, it's very simple but Hotmail just won't show the images in my html email sent with php.

Here's the code :

```
<div id="body" style="font-family:Arial, Tahoma;font-size:12px;width:650px;margin:auto;">
    <a href="http://www.2hu.fr/"><img src="http://www.2hu.fr/img/logo.png" alt="Logo 2HU" width="129" height="49"/></a>
    <div id="notification" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #C4CDE0;padding:10px;">
        <?php echo $content;    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="font-size:11px;text-align:center;color:#999;">
        Mail automatique de notification - Aller sur <a href="http://www.2hu.fr/" style="color:#d84c1c;">2hu.fr</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see it's very simple but the image doesn't show up and if I check the source the hotmail url gives a 404 error while when I go to the image url directly with my browser it works perfectly.

An idea anyone ?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that Hotmail will modify a message's `img src`, I find that very unlikely, and bizarre to say the least. It will (most) probably scrap out CSS, but images? Hm... - You'd need to post the email's headers to be 100%. Probably something else is causing this. Or, it's probably blocking it; sure but not "modifying it".

Comment: The hotmail url is this one : https://dub119.mail.live.com/Handlers/ImageProxy.mvc?bicild=&canary=y0EbDbw2%2be4PhQz5wACOBoLek9X%2bU5X2xNoVZsEsRak%3d0&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.2hu.fr%2fimg%2flogo.png and I checked others mails, it's the same for others images and it works for them. Headers are content-type : tex/html

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching the image data directly as [base64](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter)

Comment: I don't want it to be attached but simply displayed

Answer (score -1):

You may be better off working with [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php)

Comment: it solved me some problem similar problems to what you have know.